# Coffeescript changes class for all radio forms instead of for just the one that was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a series of radio buttons in groups of three (for each step of a quiz).  If the radio button chosen is "video", I would like to show the "videoCreator" div.  If it is "excel", the "excelCreator" div, etc.  These divs are just additional form items below the radio buttons to allow the user to enter more information.

My problem is that the coffeescript below works, except that it changes all of the radio forms.  For example lets say step 1 is video, and the video div shows.  If I change step 2 to the excel radio button, the excel div shows for all steps (radio forms) including the first, which was supposed to stay video.  I think I need to create a variaable, but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Coffeescript

```
$(".excelCreator").hide()
$(".videoCreator").hide()
$(".mcCreator").hide()
$(".stepRadio").change ->
  if @value is "video" and @checked
    $(".videoCreator").show()
  else if @value is "excel" and @checked
    $(".excelCreator").show()
  else if @value is "multiple_choice" and @checked
    $(".mcCreator").show()
  else
    $(".excelCreator").hide()
    $(".videoCreator").hide()
    $(".mcCreator").hide()
```

Here is the show template with the radio buttons

```
 <div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :media_type, "Excel" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :media_type, 'excel', :checked => true, class: 'icheck stepRadio' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :media_type, "Video" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :media_type, 'video', class: 'icheck stepRadio' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :media_type, "Multiple Choice" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :media_type, 'multiple_choice', class: 'icheck stepRadio' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the options I would like shown based upon the radio buttons above in the same view

```
<div class="excelCreator">
    <%= f.label :link, "Excel Link" %>
    <%= f.text_field :link, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :answer, "Excel Answer (#)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :answer, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
</div>

<div class="videoCreator">
    <%= f.label :link, "Video Link" %>
    <%= f.text_field :link, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
</div>

<div class="mcCreator">
    <%= f.label :choice_one, "Choice One" %>
    <%= f.text_field :choice_one, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :choice_two, "Choice Two" %>
    <%= f.text_field :choice_two, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :choice_three, "Choice Three" %>
    <%= f.text_field :choice_three, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :choice_four, "Choice Four" %>
    <%= f.text_field :choice_four, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :answer, "MC Answer (#)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :answer, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
</div>
```

here is an example of the html that is output for one of the form fields

```
 <div>
      <label for="course_levels_attributes_0_steps_attributes_0_media_type">Excel</label>
      <input checked="checked" class="icheck stepRadio" id="course_levels_attributes_0_steps_attributes_0_media_type_excel" name="course[levels_attributes][0][steps_attributes][0][media_type]" type="radio" value="excel" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) all three at the beginning of the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler and then [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) the specific one that needed to be shown. Something like this:

```
$(".stepRadio").change ->
  # Hide all the extra `<div>`s
  $(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()

  # Show the one that we care about.
  if @value is "video"
    $(".videoCreator").show()
  else if @value is "excel"
    $(".excelCreator").show()
  else if @value is "multiple_choice"
    $(".mcCreator").show()

# This initializes things. Since you have `:checked => true`
# on the first radio button, `:checked` will always match one
# radio button.
$('.stepRadio:checked').change()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GVX2Z/

You don't need the extra `@checked` tests in your `change` handler either, the callback will only be called for the radio button that is currently checked so checking `@checked` just adds unnecessary noise.

---

If you have multiple sets of radio buttons then the easiest thing to do would be to wrap the radio buttons and their extra `<div>`s in a common container:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- radio buttons -->
    <!-- extra divs -->
</div>
```

and then use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to localize things to just the container in question:

```
$(".stepRadio").change ->
  $container = $(@).closest('.container')
  $container.find(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()
  if @value is "video"
    $container.find(".videoCreator").show()
  else if @value is "excel"
    $container.find(".excelCreator").show()
  else if @value is "multiple_choice"
    $container.find(".mcCreator").show()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2XAP2/

Comment: Hi Mu, the code you posted is much cleaner, but leaves me with the same problem.  For example, if you were to take your fiddle and add two more sets of radio buttons with the same class, any changes in selection of any radio button would display the changed class for all 3 radio button sets rather than just for the set it was changed on.  Ie if you have 'video' selected on set 1 and you have excel selected on set 2 - if you change set 2 selection to MC, it also would change set 1's display dive to MC, although it still is on 'video'.

Comment: So you have multiple sets of radio buttons each with their own extra `<div>`s?